# How to get post IDs of posts which are Sticky and those which lies in a Particular category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to get IDs of posts which are in a 'featured' category. But can I retrieve those posts as well which are also sticky, using the same query?

```
$post_ids = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts'   => 8, 
  'category_name'    => 'featured',
  'orderby'          => 'date',
  'post_type'        => 'post',
  'fields'        => 'ids'
));
```

Right now I am using two queries to get the desired results, but I think there is a better way to do this:

```
  //get featured ids
  $post_ids = get_posts(array(
     'numberposts'   => 5, 
     'category_name'    => 'featured',
     'orderby'          => 'date',
     'post_type'        => 'post',
     'fields'        => 'ids'
  )); 
  //get sticky id
  $sticky_post_ids = get_posts(array(
     'numberposts'   => '1', 
     'orderby'          => 'date',
     'post_type'        => 'post',
     'fields'        => 'ids'
     'post__in'     => get_option('sticky_posts')
  ));
```

Comment: All sticky posts, or sticky posts within the desired category?

Comment: Hi @FaisalAshfaq can you please specify what you are actually after. Do you need two lists of results or just one? And what exactly do you need in them.

Comment: Actually I need IDs of 1 latest sticky post and 5 lastest posts in featured category @cale_b

Comment: I repeat my question: 1 latest sticky *from all sticky posts*, or from within the desired category?